# How to import a .p12 or pem certificate into a java keystore?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I am trying to call HTTPS web service, the documentation of that WS include some certificates files

```
1231181189.key
1231181189.p7b
1231181189.pem
Root CA.pem
1231181189.p12
```

how to import `.p12` or `.pem` or `.p7b` certificate into a java keystore?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle JRE comes with a tool called "keytool" that allows you to import and export certs and key pairs into a Java keystore.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html